# How to make this System.Serializable class agnostic?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's the principle:

- I have a lot of Ajax exchanges
- I have a `System.Serializable` class is the result of the Ajax call
- I always have 2 functions:

  - the function to make the call
  - the function to analyze the call

The function that makes the call gets a callback as a parameter, makes the call, and when it's done, calls back with the `System.Serializable` class.

Here's an example:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class JsonState
{
    public int state;
    public string message;
    public JsonData data;
}
```

And in my class:

```
public class DataController : MonoBehaviour {
    public delegate void CallbackAjaxStateFinished(JsonState j);
    public CallbackAjaxStateFinished cbAjaxStateFinished = null;

    public void AjaxStateGet(CallbackAjaxStateFinished cb=null)
    {
        /* make the Ajax call*/
        cbAjaxStateFinished = cb;
        new HTTPRequest(
            new Uri(baseURL + _urlGetState),
            HTTPMethods.Get, AjaxStateGetFinished
        ).Send();
    }

    private void AjaxStateGetFinished(
        HTTPRequest request, HTTPResponse response
    ) {
        if (response == null) {
            return;
        }
        JsonState j = null;
        try {
            j = JsonUtility.FromJson<JsonState>(response.DataAsText);
            if (cbAjaxStateFinished != null) {
                cbAjaxStateFinished(j);
            }
        } catch (ArgumentException) { /* Conversion problem */
            TryDisplayFatalError(FatalErrors[FatalError.ConversionProblem2]);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have already 3 Ajax calls like this, always the same principle, here are the 3 callbacks, to give you an overview:

```
public CallbackAjaxStateFinished cbAjaxStateFinished = null;
public CallbackAjaxGamesToJoinFinished cbAjaxGamesToJoinFinished = null;
public CallbackAjaxGameDetailFinished cbAjaxGameDetailFinished = null;
```

But I'll add another one and copy/paste the code to send/receive above with only 2 minor modifications:

- change the `CallbackXxx` type
- change the `System.Serializable` class

I'm new to C#, is there a way to make this generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is not that complex, assuming your callbacks are always of the form `void(SomeStateclass)`.

Replacing the `JSonState` with a generic T in the above code will do the trick. This is what you'll end up wih:

```
// The DataController takes a generic T respresenting one of your State classes
// notice that we need a constraint for the type T to have a parameterless constructor
public class DataController<T> : MonoBehaviour where T: new()
{ 
    // the delegate takes the generic type, so we only need one
    public delegate void CallbackAjaxFinished(T j);

    public CallbackAjaxFinished cbAjaxFinished = null;

    public void AjaxStateGet(CallbackAjaxFinished cb=null)
    {
        /* make the Ajax call*/
        cbAjaxFinished = cb;
        new HTTPRequest(
            new Uri(baseURL + _urlGetState),
            HTTPMethods.Get, AjaxStateGetFinished
        ).Send();
    }

    private void AjaxStateGetFinished(
        HTTPRequest request, HTTPResponse response
    ) {
        if (response == null) {
            return;
        }
        // here we use the default keyword to get 
        // an instance of an initialized stronglytyped T
        T j = default(T);
        try {
            // the T goes into the FromJson call as that one was already generic
            j = JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(response.DataAsText);
            if (cbAjaxFinished != null) {
                cbAjaxFinished(j);
            }
        } catch (ArgumentException) { /* Conversion problem */
            TryDisplayFatalError(FatalErrors[FatalError.ConversionProblem2]);
        }
    }
}
```

That is all. Your datacontroller class is now generic.

You'll use it like so:

```
var dc = new DataController<JsonState>()
dc.AjaxStateGet( (v) => {
   v.Dump("jsonstate");
});

var dc2 = new DataController<JsonState2>();
dc2.AjaxStateGet( (v) => {
   v.Dump("jsonstate2");
});
```

Comment: I had a lot of questions to ask about C# but your answer here solved them! **`;^)`** Thanks a lot!